# How to write large array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to write two dimensional array with size 784 x 30, it keep getting error 
**java: code too large**
, is there any alternative to do this? Thanks

Comment: Load the data from a file.

Comment: http://imgur.com/JV8u1tp works fine can you brief your post...